# Javafx WARNING: Resource "style.css" not found intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am making a simple Javafx application with FXML.
My files are all in the same package:

- MainApp.java
- MainAppController.java
- style.css
- MainApp.fxml

My root tag from the `.fxml` file contains:

```xml
<GridPane fx:id="myRootPanel"
          alignment="CENTER"
          maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
          minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
          stylesheets="@style.css"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.MainAppController">
```

as you see there is a `stylesheets="@style.css"`, which was even autocompleted by Intellij.

When I open this `.fxml` file in Scenebuilder, the css is applied correctly, but when I run the project, I get following console messages:

`null/style.css` and `WARNING: Resource "style.css" not found.`

I have added `*.css` to my Resource patterns, did a clean build, invalidated cache, but none of these resolve my problem.

I tried to make a simple application in NetBeans, and when I run that project there, the CSS is applied correctly. Because of this, I think there might be a problem/setting in the Intellij IDE to solve this... Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks in advance.
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `@style.css` does not work, instead I used the relative folder path, starting from the root (`src`): `/css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it a bit differently. The problem was that I create the CSS dynamically based on stored settings (e.g. font family, font size, etc. with selection by the user). I called it dynamic.css.

So, what worked for me in my Main Window Controller was this:

```
String csspath = "";
try
{
    csspath = MainController.class.getResource("/CSS/dynamic.css").toExternalForm();
    mainscene.getStylesheets().add(csspath);
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    String msg = "\nERROR MainController::loadStylesheet 2040: err=";
    msg += e.getMessage();
    msg += "\nURL:";
    msg += csspath;
    msg += "\n\n";
    System.out.println(msg);
    mainscene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
}
```